# reshape a pandas dataframe index to columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

Consider the below pandas Series object,

```
index = list('abcdabcdabcd')
df = pd.Series(np.arange(len(index)), index = index)
```

My desired output is,

```
   a  b   c   d
0  0  1   2   3
1  4  5   6   7
2  8  9  10  11
```

I have put some effort with pd.pivot_table, pd.unstack and probably the solution lies with correct use of one of them. The closest i have reached is

```
df.reset_index(level = 1).unstack(level = 1)
```

but this does not gives me the output i my looking for

// here is something even closer to the desired output, but i am not able to handle the index grouping.

```
df.to_frame().set_index(df1.values, append = True, drop  = False).unstack(level = 0)

     a    b     c     d
0   0.0  NaN   NaN   NaN
1   NaN  1.0   NaN   NaN
2   NaN  NaN   2.0   NaN
3   NaN  NaN   NaN   3.0
4   4.0  NaN   NaN   NaN
5   NaN  5.0   NaN   NaN
6   NaN  NaN   6.0   NaN
7   NaN  NaN   NaN   7.0
8   8.0  NaN   NaN   NaN
9   NaN  9.0   NaN   NaN
10  NaN  NaN  10.0   NaN
11  NaN  NaN   NaN  11.0
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A bit more general solution using [`cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) to get new index values, and [`pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) to do the reshaping:

```
# Reset the existing index, and construct the new index values.
df = df.reset_index()
df.index = df.groupby('index').cumcount()

# Pivot and remove the column axis name.
df = df.pivot(columns='index', values=0).rename_axis(None, axis=1)
```

The resulting output:

```
   a  b   c   d
0  0  1   2   3
1  4  5   6   7
2  8  9  10  11
```

Comment: indeed very thoughtful

Answer (score -1):

Here is a way that will work if the index is always cycling in the same order, and you know the "period" (in this case 4):

```
>>> pd.DataFrame(df.values.reshape(-1,4), columns=list('abcd'))
   a  b   c   d
0  0  1   2   3
1  4  5   6   7
2  8  9  10  11
>>>
```

Comment: the index cycling will be in the same order. But, the index length may not necessarily be divisible by 4, for example ['a','b','a','b','a'] cannot be reshaped into a (2,2) array in numpy. However, I guess in pandas, it will be fill NaN values. Hope I am making sense:)

Comment: @SirajS. in other words, it might not terminate at the end of a cycle?

Comment: yes. the length of elements maynot be perfectly divisible with the length of the columns. in which case a numpy.reshape() will not work